# Hadoop Multi-Node Cluster Set-up Basic Questions

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I'm trying to set up a multi-node Apache Hadoop cluster. I'm following their tutorial here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html. I've set up single-node Hadoop set-ups on each individual node, as well as Sun Java installed on each. Unfortunately, the documentation is not very clear and a bit outdated. Am I supposed to (under the 'Configuring the Hadoop Daemons' sections) update those files (.conf/*-site.xml) on every single node?
Also, how am I supposed to locate the host:port/IP:port pair for each node? 
Sorry, I am new to all of this. Thank you in advance for your help!